# Inserting a file name to Postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, for-loop

I have the following code to insert the file name to Postgres table called 'logs'

```
c = engine.connect()
conn = c.connection
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT filename from logs" )
rows1 = cur.fetchall()
rows1 = [x[0] for x in rows1]

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        fname = os.path.join(root,filename)
        if os.path.isfile(fname) and fname[-4:] == '.log':
            if fname not in rows1:
            print fname
            cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO logs(filename) VALUES (%(fname)s)""")
            conn.commit()
```

I am getting the error

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1:  INSERT INTO logs(filename) VALUES (%(fname)s)
```

May I know where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't passed any parameters to the query, so no replacement will be made; the adapter will pass the literal string `(%(fname)s)` to Postgres.

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO logs(filename) VALUES (%(fname)s)""", {'fname': fname'})
```